# Grab single image from website on a regular schedule

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to grab the same image (from a website) every *x* minutes to eventually make a timelapse video.

My issues are:

- setting up the schedule to grab the image and
- saving the image with the time/date as part of the file name.

Would it be best to use something like Python?

Comment: Do you necessarily need Python? This can easily be done with normal Bash commands and `wget`. Have you tried anything or did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: I'm reasonably competent with DOS batch files, but have little experience with Bash (beyond ls and shutdown!). I assumed that Python would probably be the answer, but I'm happy with Bash.  I'll be trying this out tonight. Many thanks.

Comment: slhck - thanks for the assistance, it worked!  I want to save the image files to a subdirectory of my home directory called pdm-5min.  I have tried to modify the output statement but can't get it to work. I have tried -O ~/pdm-5min/"${timestamp}.png" and "~/pdm-5min/"${timestamp}.png" but no joy.  Further assistance appreciated! Nigel

Comment: Could you post this comment under the answer below? @justbrowsing will then get a notification. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to include what your current status is or what exactly doesn't work? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Let's use your avatar for example** (save to `/opt/download-avatar`)

```
#!/bin/bash
URL="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/554f043fa658cba9bbc2ee4c6d4e052d?d=identicon"
timestamp=$(date +%F_%T);
wget "$URL" -O "${timestamp}.png"
```

*Note: it may be better to save the filenames as seconds from epoch `timestamp=$(date +%s)`*

**Create a [cron job to run it every 5 mintues](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/)** (save to `/etc/cron.d/timelapse-avatar`)

```
#!/bin/sh
*/5 * * * * /opt/download-avatar
```

**Make the scripts executable**

```
chmod +x /opt/download-avatar
sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.d/timelapse-avatar
```

---

**If you don't want to use `cron` then simply** (save to `~/start-timelapse`)

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
URL="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/554f043fa658cba9bbc2ee4c6d4e052d?d=identicon"

if [ -z "$input" ]; then
  echo "USAGE: $0 [interval in minutes]" 
  exit 1
else
  interval=$((60*input));
fi

while [ 0 = 0 ]; do
  timestamp=$(date +%s)
  wget "$URL" -O "${timestamp}.png"
  echo "Sleeping for $input minutes"
  sleep "$interval"
done;
```

**Make executable and run at 7 minute intervals**

```
chmod +x ~/start-timelapse
cd ~
./start-timelapse 7
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck).

[Nigel](https://superuser.com/users/247546/nigel), by default `cron` runs as *root* user. Not pertinent to this question but technically it runs as a "special user", non-interactively, without environmental variables such as `$PATH`, without the `dbus` session id, without the `X` session id, etc.

`~/` is shorthand for a user's home directory (also see the environmental variable `$HOME`). By default for *users*, this would be for example `/home/nigel` but for *root*, this is `/root` therefore probably **cron** has been saving them to `/root/pdm-5min`. You could use:

```
wget "$URL" -O "/home/nigel/pdm-5min/${timestamp}.png"
```

BUT, the files would be owned by *root*, so *nigel* wouldn't be able to move, delete, edit them unless you give yourself permission as *root* (or through `sudo`)

Therefore you might choose to run `cron` as your user *nigel*.

```
#!/bin/sh
*/5 * * * * nigel /opt/download-avatar
```

Make sure the directory you are saving to exists, might want to add directly before the `wget` line:

```
mkdir -p /home/nigel/pdm-5min/
```

Lastly, be careful with your `"` (quotes). Use them so that variables retain whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.) but make sure each single or double-quote has a matching one, it's not optional.

Comment: Note that in the latter variant, the download would eventually stop if the shell was quit or the terminal was exited, etc.

Comment: @Justbrowsing: thanks for the assistance, it worked! I want to save the image files to a subdirectory of my home directory called pdm-5min. I have tried to modify the output statement but can't get it to work. Nothing is saving.  I have tried -O ~/pdm-5min/"${timestamp}.png" and "~/pdm-5min/"${timestamp}.png" but no joy. Further assistance appreciated! Nigel – Nigel

Comment: @justbrowsing - many thanks for the rapid and concise reply. All points raised very useful,and I am now successfully running cron as me, rather than as root, and saving my grabbed images to the correct folders. Thanks again.  Appreciated.